# Tcl file for RMST protocol

Tags: tcl, ns2

**RMST** comes with `ns-2`. It has many file under the **diffusion3** directory `~ns/diffusion3/filters/rmst`. But I didn't find any `tcl` scripts in `ns2.35` package for testing an example scenario. Is there any `tcl` scripts (`*.tcl`) for **RMST**?

Comment: Answered here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ns-users/PM3jmZ6JS5I ... **and** https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ns-users/B0nIIeza-E0

Comment: Dear Knudfl, Reall Thank You. But from the link http://mailman.isi.edu/pipermail/ns-users/2011-August/070914.html the Directed_Diffusion is used as a routing protocol. Does it be possible to to use directed_diffusion for rmst protocol? And also I have tried to attached the rmst as DiffApp to the node that conflict NS2 that says agents should be attached to nodes and applications to the agents. It says that No DiffusionApp agent created for this node! How can I solve this?
                                                Thank you    in advance